# Найти ссылку по содержимому и заменить текст. Как сделать на JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a class="menu_core_main core_main_page" href="/ne/browse-pages">Pages</a>
```

Нужно найти ссылку по тексту "Pages" и если такая ссылка присутствует на странице, тогда поменять ее текст на Sponsorship. Интересует реализация на jQuery и JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На **jQuery**:

```
$("a:contains('Pages')").text('Sponsorship'); // Товарищ Yevgeny Skuridin
```

На **JS** (тут чуть сложнее, sizzle выиграл этот раунд, нечего сказать):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(e){
  if(e.innerHTML == 'Pages')
    e.innerHTML = 'Sponsorship';
});
```

Comment: break ? правда?

Comment: @disfated, Поставил на автомате, понятия не имею выйдет ли или нет - ни разу не пробовал на практике. Да и не критично это.

Comment: Ну, вообще-то, критично, так как это не валидный синтаксис. Потом, гонять цикл до конца если ссылка нашлась где-то в начале - как-то не кошерно.

Comment: Интересно было бы сравнить производительность jQuery и ванильный JS...

Comment: Хм, и правда ошибку бросает, можно пошаманить с исключаниями, но .. Вдруг не одна ссылка с таким текстом? Пусть тогда всё проверяет.

Answer (score 2):

`$("a:contains('Pages')").text('Sponsorship');` — найти все ссылки, в тексте которых содержится слово "Pages", и заменить текст на "Sponsorship".

Answer (score 1):

Реализация на чистом JS (так как спрашивали *"реализацию на jQuery **и** JS"*)

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, _i = links.length; i < _i; i++) {
    if (links[i].innerHTML == 'Pages') {
        links[i].innerHTML = 'Sponsorship';
        break;
    }
}
```

Громоздко, но зато работает на любом браузере, который сможете откопать, независим и быстрее jQuery в 10 раз - [пруф](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lq6cbh9/):

[image]

Вот сколько суеты можно создать вокруг 15-ти секундной задачи! :)